# Customization of List on User Group bases

Tags: content-query-web-part, personalization

I have created a custom list in SharePoint 2010.

I like to do the customization of this list by user who is logged in.

Ex:

- If User "A" is from Super Admin Group. He/she is able to see All Data of List.
- If User "B" is from Employee Group. He/She is able to see only list items which is added by "B" but not the whole list.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I got solution of my Problem.

For this you need to crate View of List and Assign the Permission to Each Group for the List.

Setting in List Setting Menu->Advanced settings
In Item Level Permission Portion Select 'Read items that were created by the user' and 'Create items and edit items that were created by the user' Radio Buttons.

These changes you only need to do and You get List wise Permission to List

Thanks